# С#. Error "Expected method with different signature". But show same signature

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, delegates, class-library

I have event handler method `c_CriticalSituationHappened` in `Program.cs`

```
void c_CriticalSituationHappened(object sender, CriticalSituationGacEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TypeDisrepair != TypeDisrepairGac.None)
    {
        start_time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        typeDisrepair = e.TypeDisrepair;
        WriteLine("Crit sit time: " + start_time);
        isStarted = true;
     }
}
```

If I move it to the class library, I import it.

```
public class CorrectBehaviorCheck
{
    public void CriticalSituationHappened1(object sender, CriticalSituationGacEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TypeDisrepair != TypeDisrepairGac.None)
        {
            criticalSituationStartTime = DateTime.Now;
            TypeDisrepair = e.TypeDisrepair;
            Console.WriteLine("111");
            isStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Signatures remain exactly the same.
**BUT** if a try

```
using cbc = mymodule.CorrectBehaviorCheck;
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        cbc a = new cbc();
        CriticalSituationHappened += a.CriticalSituationHappened1;
    }
}
```

**INSTEAD OF**

```
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        CriticalSituationHappened += c_CriticalSituationHappened;
    }
}
```

I've got an error `Expected a method with 'void CriticalSituationHappened1(object?, CriticalSituationGacEventArgs)' signature` What am I doing wrong? Both methods have the same signature. Why does the program break when I put a method in a class library?

in Program.cs:

```
protected virtual void OnCriticalSituationHappened(CriticalSituationGacEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<CriticalSituationGacEventArgs> handler = CriticalSituationHappened;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
public static event EventHandler<CriticalSituationGacEventArgs> CriticalSituationHappened;
```

Comment: Can you show how `CriticalSituationHappened` is defined along with any delegate?

Comment: Added at the end

Comment: Which assembly is `CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` is defined in? Do you have multiple definitions of `CriticalSituationGacEventArgs`?

Comment: One definition in project with Program.cs and one definition in imported module. (Code is the same) public class CriticalSituationGacEventArgs : EventArgs { public string Message {get; set;}; public TypeDisrepairGac {get; set;}}. TypeDisrepairGac is the enum list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring due to multiple definitions of `CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` across assemblies. To illustrate a bit, in the main assembly (let's call it `A`) we have:

```cs
namespace A
{
    using cbc = B.CorrectBehaviorCheck;

    public class CriticalSituationGacEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }   

    public class Program
    {
        public static event EventHandler<A.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs> CriticalSituationHappened;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cbc a = new cbc();
            CriticalSituationHappened += a.CriticalSituationHappened1;
            CriticalSituationHappened(null, new A.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs { Message = "Hello!" });
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the external assembly (let's call it `B`) we have:

```cs
namespace B
{
    public class CriticalSituationGacEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CorrectBehaviorCheck
    {
        public void CriticalSituationHappened1(object sender, B.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening in CorrectBehaviorCheck.CriticalSituationHappened1: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the error at `CriticalSituationHappened += a.CriticalSituationHappened1`. To understand that a bit more, we can more explicitly define this as:

```
CriticalSituationHappened += (object sender, A.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs e) => a.CriticalSituationHappened1(sender, e);
```

This is trying to pass `A.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` to a parameter expecting `B.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` which gives an error of:

```
CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'A.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs' to 'B.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs'
```

because the compiler has no way of knowing how to convert from one type to the other. Given your situation, there are a couple of options to get around this:

## 1. Manually convert the event args

```cs
    CriticalSituationHappened += (sender, e) => 
        a.CriticalSituationHappened1(sender, new B.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs 
                                     { 
                                         Message = e.Message,
                                         // set other properties
                                     });
```

## 2. Define the event args once in a shared assembly

Create a new project (e.g. `MyEventArgs`) and define `CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` once in that project. Then `A` and `B` can both reference `MyEventArgs.CriticalSituationGacEventArgs` in defining the event (in `A`) and handling the event (in `B`). This also avoids circular dependencies of having the single type defined in either `A` or `B`.